# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I'm just going through the course and got an error message about my props. I'm new with React JS and can not understand what I wrote wrong, cause it's the same code that I saw on the course. Thank you in advance!

Error message:

[image]

App.js

```
import ExpenseItem from './components/ExpenseItem';

function App() {
  const expenses = [
    {
      title:'New TV', amount: 294.67, date: new Date(2020,2,25),
      title:'Car Insurance', amount: 294.67, date: new Date(2020,2,25),
      title:'Toilet Paper', amount: 294.67, date: new Date(2020,2,25)
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
     <h2>Let's get started!</h2>
     <ExpenseItem title={expenses[0].title} amount={expenses[0].amount} date={expenses[0].date}></ExpenseItem>
     <ExpenseItem title={expenses[1].title} amount={expenses[1].amount} date={expenses[1].date}></ExpenseItem>
     <ExpenseItem title={expenses[2].title} amount={expenses[2].amount} date={expenses[2].date}></ExpenseItem>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ExpenseItem.js

```
import './ExpenseItem.css';

function ExpenseItem(props){
  
    return (
    <div className="expense-item">
        <div>{props.date.toISOString()}</div>
        <div className="expense-item__description">
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
            <div className="expense-item__price">${props.amount}</div>
        </div>
    </div>)
    
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array `expenses` wrong.

```
const expenses = [
    { title: "New TV", amount: 294.67, date: new Date(2020, 2, 25)},
    { title: "Car Insurance", amount: 294.67, date: new Date(2020, 2, 25) },
    { title: "Toilet Paper", amount: 294.67, date: new Date(2020, 2, 25) },
  ];
```

Comment: @Sanktos - Also look at using the map function to iterate through the expenses array and create the ExpenseItem components rather than manually creating them.

Comment: Big thank you, @Viet! Didn't see this error.